# Mongoose updating documents: updates just the first one

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a strange problem. I do this query in a node.js server using mongoose: `Transaction.update({username : user.username}, {$set: { pending : true }} ...` that basically should set in all the items with the username equal to `user.username` the attribute `pending: true`. The problem is that it only sets it to the first element it finds. Is that possible? Because I have always 2 elements in my DB and sometimes one is pending, sometimes the other but not both of them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way mongoose/mongodb work is that you must specify when you want to allow a multi update, via the options parameter:

```
Transaction.update({username : user.username}, {$set: { pending : true }}, {multi: true});
```